# Declare array of TABLE%TYPE

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle10g, package

I am using the to receive collection from Java to PL/SQL procedure to insert records into table.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE PROJECT_TYPE IS OBJECT
(
    project_id NUMBER,
    project_desc VARCHAR2 (10),
    project_title VARCHAR2 (25)
);

PROCEDURE project_values (parray IN project_type)
IS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO  projects (project_id, project_desc, project_title)
        SELECT  *
          FROM  TABLE (parray);
END;
```

Instead of the above I would like to use

```
TYPE array IS TABLE OF projects%ROWTYPE INDEX BY VARCHAR2 (25);
```

and I have tried to call as

```
INSERT INTO  projects (project_id, project_desc, project_title)
select * from table(p_array);
```

I am getting the following errors

```
PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
PL/SQL: ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item
```

How can I use associative arrays instead of type object there by declaring all columns explicitly? if I could use  `projects%ROWTYPE` then I do not need to declare all columns.

And what is the best approach? use associative arrays of `TABLE%TYPE` or declare all columns as TYPE object?

**Edit 1**

I would like to know the following and can this be achieved in database level?

1. Can I use Table of array if I am would like to pass array from Java to a procedure? If so can I declare it at package level or it should be at schema level?
2. Instead of manually writing all columns while creating type as object, if I can create array of table type, then it will be easy to manage.

Comment: I don't think that you really got any choice here, the `%ROWTYPE` is known only in PLSql and not in SQL, so you can't create a schema level type as Array of <table>%ROWTYPE and can't use plsql types in a table function without casting it to a scema level type... Or maybe I don't understand your question right ?

Comment: So best approach and practice would be to declare all columns as TYPE Object?

Comment: No, that would not be best practice.

Comment: @APC So how to go about this and what is the best practise?

Comment: Try to wrap "table(p_array)" in a view like CREATE VIEW P_ARRAY_V AS SELECT * FROM table(p_array).

Comment: @theodojo Could you provide an example?

Comment: I am not sure it will work, just try the wrapping above (as I wrote it) and then do an INSERT INTO PROJECTS SELECT * FROM P_ARRAY_V - instead of table(p_array). I remember once I was able to trick Oracle this way.

Comment: @theodojo `p_array` is limited to package and even if I create it at schema level, it does gives error when I am trying to create a view?

Comment: As I've explained in other threads, you can't use the %TYPE and %ROWNUM in SQL context, just as A. B. Cade said in the first comment. And you have to define the object type and TABLE type in database level, not package level. So you have to define each column for the object type.

Comment: If p_array is not present in package specification, there is no way for sql to see it. If it is there, then it can be accessed by its fully qualified name, e.g. PACKAGE_NAME.p_array